# Taking the limit of a volume integral as its domain tends to zero volume: what is the correct notation, and how to do it correctly?

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, notation

Basically, I'm not a mathematician, and I'm trying to figure out how to be "precise" in terms of notation and logic for these concepts.

Say I have a function $\lambda(\mathbf{x}) \geq 0$, defined on some $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which is "nice." I define the measure (this would be a measure right?):

$\Lambda (B) = \int _{B} \lambda(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x}$

where we are considering compact (?) domains $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $\lambda$ is continuous over $B$, it seems obvious to me to state that as B becomes arbitrarily small, $\Lambda (B)$ will become $\lambda (\mathbf{x}_B)|B|$, where I'm saying $\mathbf{x}_B$ is some point in $B$.

How would I state this as an equation where I'm taking the limit? Like what is the correct notation for taking the limit of B as it becomes an infinitesimally small volume at $\mathbf{x}_B$? Also, what are the conditions on $\lambda$ for this work? Just that it has to be continuous?

Comment: As written, it seems to me that $\Lambda(B)$ should tend to 0 as $B$ "tends to a point". Maybe you are after the *average* of $\lambda$ over the set $B$, rather than its "$\lambda$-measure"?

Comment: Ah yeah you're right. Yeah either the average instead, or for me it would be the same to say that $\Lambda (B)$ goes to $\lambda (\mathbf{x}_B) |B|$ where $|B|$ is the volume of $B$. Would you also call $|B|$ the cardinality of B? I've heard that before too. I'll edit the question.